# Inappropriate deletion of answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, deleted-answer

[When Christians say "the Lord" in everyday speech, do they mean Jesus or the Father?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/80984/when-christians-say-the-lord-in-everyday-speech-do-they-mean-jesus-or-the-fat)

This topic was answered according to the scriptures - this is Christianity after all.

The excuse given to DELETE was that it did not answer the Q. I claim it certainly did.

Granted, there was some extra content to the core topic, but was also intrinsic to the answer content.

The community bias is vividly displayed with the accepted answer (no idea why) which is plainly very poor quality and has been rated NINE!

It's poor quality because it is too brief, lacking credibility with a claim that is made, and a random thrust about a trinity which has nothing to do with the question.

Deleting my answer is a heavy-handed approach and is unwarranted and unjustified. Has the bias of some mod/s gone too far in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever flag D.J.'s answer as not an answer?  Moderators don't necessarily go out of their way to delete answers.

I think this is a question about Christian culture, not necessarily theology.  Or you could say it's a question of confused theology.

Mods are exception handlers, not just bad answer hunters and definitely not doctrine enforcers.

Frankly, you're right, the accepted answer has nothing to do with "What Christians do" or even an attempt at an overview of Christianity.

Also, this is an unwritten rule, but since I answered a question on there, I'm not going to handle flags on that question unless nobody else does.

So I think you have a half a point, but it doesn't mean that your answer, which is clearly attempting to prove something concrete about the nature of God whereas the question is about usage or what are most Christians thinking.  Now, clearly a good answer would either say, "this is what Christians who hold God is a Trinity of Persons are thinking", which is what the accepted answer did.  A bad answer would say this is how it is.

Your answer was a claim lacking a doctrine, nobody knows what you're talking about.  If you said, Seventh Day Adventists say... or Jehovah's Witnesses say... But on the level, it's an assertion that is going to be downvoted into oblivion and it might just be more merciful to leave it deleted.

Answer (score 3):

> This topic was answered according to the scriptures - this is Christianity after all.

The question doesn't ask for an answer from the scriptures. A legitimate answer to the question might never directly quote the scriptures at all. The question asks who *most* Christians are thinking of when they say "the Lord". Imagine there was a survey asking 100 million Christians who they think of when they say "the Lord" - if you could reference such a survey then that would be an excellent answer to the question. The scriptures would be irrelevant.

More importantly *your* interpretation of the scriptures are irrelevant. So are *mine*. We don't do individual interpretation of the Bible here. This site is about documenting the beliefs and practices of Christian groups. You need to be able to demonstrate that what you say is what is believe by *most* Christians. Do most Christians believe that "lord" can refer to either, but that only one is God? I don't think so. If you think so then present the evidence.

To be honest, it's not a great question. It's scoping is too implicit - probably the OP is thinking of Trinitarians, but it's always better to be explicit.

But what will never be a valid answer to that question is the beliefs of single individuals. It asks who **most Christians** are thinking of, so of course the views of individuals are not in scope.

I'm pretty sure I've seen you say before that you do not subscribe to the teachings of any denomination. Is that correct? Is there any label that you think does have accurate theology? If there isn't you need to face the fact that there will never be a time when your personal beliefs will get a hearing on this site. (Unless you publish books which become well known and other people want to ask about them...) This site works very differently to Biblical Hermeneutics. On that site unique interpretations are fine, even encouraged. What matters is not the creedal background of answerers, but the argumentation they provide in their answers. But that's not how this site works. Answers here must match the perspective asked about and present evidence that the group in question teaches what the answer says.

Comment: As noted in the comments (and other posts by inference), Biblical Unitarianism is a hat I'm happy to wear. Is that an 'accepted denomination' that might falls under the banner Christianity? The bible is the only book that references the life of Christ in context and purpose - why wouldn't the scriptures be 'good enough' or desirable/preferable?

Comment: @user47952 Okay, that's helpful to know, thank you! But as [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_unitarianism#Denominations) the two biggest denominations of Biblical Unitarians are the Christadelphians (60,000) and the CoGGC (5,000). As a small footnote in an overview answer that covered other denominations you could mention them, but if Christian Universalism is the only perspective presented? That cannot be a valid answer to the question of "who do most Christians think of when they say 'Lord'?"

Comment: Again, you say. "most". The Q doesn't specify this, and this does not need to be implied... just Christians - of which I am one for many years. Broad is the way and many that find it. Numbers of adherents mean absolutely nothing as to who is Christian and who is one nominally.

Comment: @user47952 It's implicit in the question. If the question asker wanted a survey of individuals it would have to be closed because we don't allow them.

Comment: Why do you persist with 'individuals'? I answer as a BU Christian. If we don't have the numbers to satisfy your criteria that is for you to work thru. If you choose to edit Christianity by your lens there is a larger problem.

Comment: @user47952 We can read "Christians" as "all Christians individually", or as "a generalisation of all of Christianity." The first is forbidden here. The latter is allowed through overview questions. Neither lets small denominations speak for all of Christendom. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user47952 Were you approaching the question with the intention that each answer would present one denomination's response to the question?

Comment: How else would one answer it - is this not what the site exists for - to get a rounded view of what it is to be Christian? To do that from (I would think) the foundation of scripture at least. Otherwise we'd have muslims etc. telling us what we should think and believe from their sources of wisdom.

Comment: @user47952 Okay I think that's something important to talk about. In order to protect minority groups from the tyranny of the majority we don't allow questions on this site where each answer presents a different view. Instead questions have to either target one specific group, or they ask for an overview, in which *all* answers have to cover *all of Christianity*.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was deleted for a simple reason. It violated one of the rules of the site, which is we don't get into arguments about which branch of Christianity is true. Especially we don't *start* arguments about which branch of Christianity is true.

If I may quote your answer:

> ["Lord" refers to] Either [Jesus or the Father]. They are both Lord. But only one is God. One IS God, the other Has a God.

Firstly the question didn't ask about whether Jesus is God, so stating that Jesus is  not God is not relevant in the answer. Second, only certain Christians believe that Jesus is not God (less than 2% of Christians worldwide). So stating that 98% of Christians are wrong is argumentative and against site rules. (And yes, those 98% do believe that the Bible say Jesus is God, and yes they have heard all your arguments about why you think he isn't, and no they are not convinced by them.)

You could have made your answer acceptable by leaving out the part about Jesus not being God (although it's not clear it would have added anything to the other answers.) You could have mitigated the problem by saying "From the non-Trinitarian point of view..." but unless  you had also explained how Trinitarians (the majority of Christians) used "Lord" then it wouldn't have been a useful answer.

Accusing the answers of "Trinitarian bias" doesn't make a lot of sense. The question has a "trinity" tag so it is reasonable to assume the questioner is asking from a Trinitarian point of view. It also asks about "most Christians" and most Christians are Trinitarian.

In my opinion the second-placed answer is better than mine, but I don't get to decide which is accepted.